# How can I enable ports auto-redirect on a CentOS 8 image deployed in my jelastic environment?

Tags: docker, centos, jelastic

I am trying to install the [hasura docker image for centos](https://hub.docker.com/r/hasura/graphql-engine/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=v2.0.9.centos) on a Jelastic environment. To do so, I have written the following manifest (because it is impossible to select the tag `v2.0.9.centos` in the environment setup dialog (there are too many tags):

```yaml
type: install
name: hasura

nodes:
- displayName: hasura
  count: 1
  cloudlets: 32
  nodeGroup: cp
  nodeType: docker
  image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.9.centos
```

Then, because I'm currently just playing around, I've opened a console on that hasura node and called

```sh
graphql-engine serve --database-url postgres://hasura_user:5W87vcvNVppTbv5AAjM4@node93849-my-env.hidora.com:5432/hasura
```

Now, I'd really like to access my hasura instance. The problem is that this hasura image bases on CentOS 8 and [Jelastic documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/supported-os-distributions/) says that ports auto-redirect does not work on CentOS 8.

Hasura serves on localhost:8080. What do I have to do in my centos node to expose that port 8080 to the outside?

The question is not hasura-specific. The software deployed on CentOS could be anything serving on any port.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue after running the following commands in my centos8 node:

```sh
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

where `8080` is the port hasura is serving.